# How to use tap guesture recognizer to tap on a picture and make it do something following the scenario below?

Tags: ios, swift

As a user, I want to play the game Rock, Paper, Scissors. On the view controller, I should see images for the rock, paper, and scissors. Once I tap an image to select my game piece, I want the app to randomly generate a game piece. Based on what I picked and what the app picked, I want a label to display who is the winner.

No clue where to start

needs to use tap gestures recognizer

Comment: Please read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Add `Tag` value to the `imageView` and on tap function use that to show the respective image.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.myUIImageView1.tag = 100 // replace with your imageviews and desired tag id
self.myUIImageView2.tag = 200 // replace with your imageviews and desired tag id
self.myUIImageView3.tag = 300 // replace with your imageviews and desired tag id

    // Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to all ImageViews, I've added for `myUIImageView1`
    let imageViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myUIImageViewTap(_:)))
    imageViewTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageViewTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.myUIImageView1.addGestureRecognizer(imageViewTap)
    self.myUIImageView1.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func myUIImageViewTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Based on the TAG Value you can redirect the user to particular image section.
    if let view = sender.view {
        if view.tag == 100 {
            //Image1 tapped
        } else if view.tag == 200 {
            //Image2 tapped
        } else if view.tag == 300 {
            //Image3 tapped            
         }
    }
}
```